# Composite primary key in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a composite primary key in Sql server.
The syntax I have tried is:

```
create table Installment_details
(
 constraint P_key primary key(Account_No,month),
 Account_No int not null,
     foreign key (Account_No) references Account_details(Account_no) on delete cascade,
 Month char(15) not null,
 D@te date,
 Receipt_no varchar(15),
 Amount_received int,
 Amount_left int,
 Amount_receiver char(50),
)
```

As far as I know it should create column with column name P_key for primary key but whenever I make a entry in table it doesn't show this column.

[image]

Comment: No, P_Key is not a column, it's the name of the primary key constraint.

Comment: You created the Composite key using those two fields (AccountNo, month).

Comment: isn't that name supposed to be shown in table?

Comment: No, that is only the name of the Key you created! Fields are only the ones which shows up on table.

Comment: Column names != constraint names. You never see constraint names unless you dig into system views or use Management Studio. You'll find `P_key` under `Keys`, but nowhere else. To refer to the primary key in foreign key constraints, you will also always need to name the columns involved (`(Account_No, month)`), never the constraint name itself.

Comment: You named that key as "P_key". Let's suppose if you need to delete that Key then! Then you can say, delete the key named P_Key ! That's why the naming of the keys are important too!

Comment: thanks I got it. now tell me one thing more that if I want to make a query that shows me only specific data ? Will it be like :
select * from where month='something' and account_no='something'

Comment: @AhmerMehmood yes that should work more or less. Since Account_no is an int the `something` should be a number and not have `' '` around it (since that denotes a text string). But you know, if you're asking such a basic question as that about SQL, then before you go any further I'd advise you might want to spend some time studying the basics via [tutorials](https://www.tsql.info/), [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference?view=sql-server-2017) and maybe even getting a book on the subject.

Comment: I searched this on internet throughly but could not find anything proper?
well thanks for your advice can you recommend my some good books or tutorials

Comment: See the links I already posted first of all. Or just google "SQL tutorial". Books you can find hundreds of, I wouldn't like to recommend one or the other. It depends on the level you want to start at.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about the terms you're using. It's not the same a Primary Key and a Column. For example, you're creating a Primary Key based on two existing columns, and the name P_Key it's the name of the Primary Key, which is the way SQL SERVER (in this case) can identify a row in the Table (it cannot be two rows with the same values on those two columns).
I hope this clarifies a little bit the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting it wrong P_key in your code is constraint's name not a column name.
Also composite key is not a column, it is used when you don't have a column with unique values. So you take combination of two or more column as primary key so that we can uniquely identify a row.